# Как отключить кэширование шаблонов директив AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, кэширование

Делаю приложение на Angular. Шаблоны, прописанные в $routeProvide НЕ кэшируются, а кэширование шаблонов директив отключить никак не получается. То есть если я вношу какие-то изменения в шаблон директивы, или вообще удаляю его, то после обновления страницы приложение выглядит так же, если не почистить кэш браузера. Как сделать, чтобы html шаблоны директив всегда подтягивались с сервера, а не брались из кэша?

[image: На изображении самый верхний html файл скачивается с сервера, а 4 остальных - это шаблоны директив. Они берутся из кэша. (from cache)]

Comment: Точно грешит js, а не сервак?

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно поможет добавление такой строки в метод run модуля.

```
$templateCache.removeAll();
```

Пример:

```
app.run(['$templateCache', '$rootScope', function ($templateCache, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {

            $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```